# Using Interactive Overlay to Export Geographic Coordinates

Tags: google-earth-engine, overlay

I can barely spell JavaScript, but I have envisioned an application working with or embedded in Google Earth that employs the following work flow:

1. This application is intended on working at scales of 1–10 km.
2. Apply a user-created overlay image in the Earth Viewer window, aligned to the local geographic grid, that shows detailed elevation data of the underlying terrain using chromatic scales.
3. Insert a user-created transparent overlay containing a polygon or other geometric feature on top of the first overlay.
4. Position, x-y deform, and/or rotate the geometric overlay so that its figure conforms to an underlying terrain feature revealed by the elevation overlay. Any of these alterations can be easily performed on Google Earth overlays.
5. Export to a database geographic data relating to the geometric overlay, such as its center coordinates, the rotation angle commanded, and/or x-y deformations performed on the geometric overlay for further computations and analyses.

Potential computations using such data include determining a feature's orientation to True North, its perimeter measure, area, aspect ratio (length ÷ width), eccentricity/asymmetry, and other descriptive information.

Could one create such a tool using the Google Earth Engine environment available? And if so, is there a ready resource for getting started on such an application? I haven't been able to make much headway with what is available at the GEE project.